# jcrop not cropping the right position

Tags: javascript, jcrop

I set up a webapp with jcrop where the user can choose a picture and a size with a aspect-ratio of 1:1.
When I choose a size and the crop the image with php everything's fine, but when I change the size after already choosing a size the coordinates are messed up. Since The user has to be able to always change the size on the fly, locking the other sizes when one is chosen is not a work around.

Here's the reslut of the first size(which is correct):

[image: correct image]

And here's the wrong result:

[image: wrong image]

You see: The size to be cropped is changing, but there's something weird going on with the coordinates...
This happens everytime I change the size.

Here's the code that fires when the size is changed:

```
    function checkSize()
{
    if(direction == true)
    {
        $("#prevWrap").css({"display":"none"});
        $("#prevWrap2").css({"display":"block"});

        var splitted = currRatio.split('x');
        jcrop_api.setOptions({aspectRatio:parseInt(splitted[0])/parseInt(splitted[1]),
                                      minSize:[splitted[0],splitted[0]],maxSize:[splitted[0],splitted[0]],
                                      trueSize: [accW*(rationHeight/accH),rationHeight],
                                      boxHeight:435,
                                      setSelect: [0, 0, splitted[1], splitted[1]],});
    }else
    {
         $("#prevWrap").css({"display":"block"});
        $("#prevWrap2").css({"display":"none"});

        var splitted = currRatio.split('x');

        jcrop_api.setOptions({aspectRatio:parseInt(splitted[0])/parseInt(splitted[1]),
                                      minSize:[splitted[0],splitted[0]],maxSize:[splitted[0],splitted[0]],
                                      trueSize: [rationWidth,accH*(rationWidth/accW)],
                                      boxHeight:435,
                                      setSelect: [0, 0, splitted[1], splitted[1]],});
    }
}
```

currRatio is the current ratio given as "600x600" or "700x700".
I set the min and max size to the ratio, because I want to disable changing the size.
If the image's width i bigger than its height, I want the height of the "croppingarea" to automatically scale to the height. So I set for trueSize:
trueSize: [accW*(rationHeight/accH),rationHeight], where accW is the image's actual width and accH its actual height. rationHeight again is the current ratio(so the same as splitted[0)])

The second part does the same for image with a higher height. So the with is scaled

I hope someone can figure out what I'm doing wrong